# Xubuntu Restarts Automatically after Shutdown

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown, restart

I recently installed Xubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Workstation.

Whenever I shutdown, two things happen. Either it shuts down and automatically restarts, or it hangs at shutdown with a black screen.

Searching for a solution I have tried the following:

- used

  ```
  sudo shutdown -h now
  sudo shutdown -P now
  sudo init 0
  ```
- amended and updated

  `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`
- checked the BIOS for Wake on LAN

  not an option for the DELL Precicion 7400 Workstation)
- reinstalled Xubuntu

None of these have solved the problems so far.

Anyone have any other options for me to try?

Comment: Did you read this older entry http://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot or this http://askubuntu.com/questions/349236/pc-restarts-after-a-few-seconds-when-performing-shutdown-or-suspend

Comment: Same problem here. Actually in my case was a result of some update I guess as it was working fine just few days ago. My laptop screen turns off after some minutes despite my settings.

Comment: Have you tried updating the BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

I recall having similar issues many years ago that was strangely due to the video drivers.  If you remove quiet splash from your /etc/default/grub and run sudo update-grub, you should be able to find the specific place where the shutdown is getting hung up.