# Automatic restart after the shutdown on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, process

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my lab and Issue is that, after the shutdown my desktop, automatically restart machine after x hour or minute then automatic restart or poweroff anytime.

Sometime also machines are not shutdown properly, its stuck !

Action taken :

1) On /etc/default/grub :

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"

sudo gedit /etc/modules
apm power_off=1
```

2) System packages are up to date.

Any one help me that why shutdown related issues on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/349236/pc-restarts-after-a-few-seconds-when-performing-shutdown-or-suspend

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've checked but not help this

Comment: You can also look at this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/349236/pc-restarts-after-a-few-seconds-when-performing-shutdown-or-suspend

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Checked those links, Is there any alternative way to fix this ?

Comment: look into `/var/log/syslog` for messages at time of shutdown and restart. Post any funny looking messages into your question. Sorry I haven't had the problem myself so can't say off the top of my head.

Comment: Here's another similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/485769/restart-instead-of-shutdown-after-suspend

Comment: Actually this seems like the best Q&A it doesn't show up searching here, but it shows up from google pointing back here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452750/reboot-after-shutdown-ubuntu-14-04-also-12-04-dell-latitude-e7440

Comment: Here's another one google points back here, but which doesn't show up in search here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760851/ubuntu-16-reboots-seconds-after-shutdown

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I was just going to suggest to check the BIOS of the system.  Good find!  =)

Comment: Here's a Launchpad bug report on the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1346269

Comment: Here's a great U&L Q&A on Debian which Ubuntu is based on: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139612/debian-wheezy-rebooting-instead-of-powering-off (I'm off to bed, but I'll check back in the morning on your progress)